# UIWebView in a UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, uinavigationcontroller

How can I control the title which appears in the UINavigationController with a web page which appears in a UIWebView?

I am trying to get the UINavigationController title to reflect the title of the web page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your webViewDidFinishLoad method, you'll need to call something like

```
NSString * result = [myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.title"];
```

Then you'll set up the navigation controller title:

```
self.navigationItem.title=result;
```

Unless I'm missing something from your problem description, this should work.